# os.execv without args argument

Tags: python

I want to replace the current process with a new one using os.execv, this works fine unless you don't have any arguments.

How can I call this even if I don't have an arguments to pass to the process I want to launch ?

```
# Works fine, unless the arguments tuple wouldn't exist or be empty
os.execv('process.exe', ('arg1', 'arg2'))
```

Comment: `os.execv(foo, [foo, args])` execve arg0 and arg1[0] need to have the same basename. its unclear to me if it should have the full path or just the basename, i'm surprised the execvp variant doesn't populate this for you, but you probably want the vp variant where both `foo`'s are the basename variable, unless you are hard coding your os environment on purpose

Comment: yeh im seeing `os.execv( "/usr/bin/echo",  ('string1','string2'))` prints only the 2nd param.  string1 is ignored.

Comment: oh which is explained here https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#process-management

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, after asking on IRC they pointed out why it works this way.

The first argument (arg0) is normally the filename of what you're executing (sys.argv[0] for example), so the first argument should always be the filename.

This explains why the arguments aren't optional, on IRC they said that arg0 is what the app will think its name is.

Answer (score 14):

`argv[0]` should be a string with at least one character. These three variants can resolve the problem:

```
cmd = '/usr/bin/vi'
os.execv(cmd, (' ',))
os.execv(cmd, [' '])
os.execl(cmd, ' ')
```

Usually, the first parameter of an argument list (sys.argv) is the command which had been used to invoke the application.
So it is better to use one of those:

```
cmd = '/usr/bin/vi'
os.execv(cmd, (cmd,))
os.execv(cmd, [cmd])
os.execl(cmd, cmd)
```

[os.exec* documentation on python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl)

Comment: this is a correct answer, argument at index 0 is the name of the program

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
os.execv('process',())
```

are you sure your `process` work without arguments?

Or try execl

```
os.execl('process')
```

Comment: That will give an error that the tuple is empty for me (In python 2.7), and yes I know it works without arguments, it's a py2exe package.

Comment: I'm using 2.5 so that may be the issue. Have you tried with execl() then?

Comment: Very strange that 2.7 behaves so differently than 2.5, maybe it's an OS difference, you seem to be running Windows, I've tested on Linux

Comment: It's indeed a version issue, I just compiled 2.7 on Linux and it behaves like you mention. Although os.execv('process', ['']) on Linux works, on Windows it crashes the interpreter

Comment: And I managed to get it to work with os.execv("C:\windows\system32\calc.exe", ["x"])

Comment: Python 2.6 behaves like 2.5 in this respect

Comment: Guess I'll have to ask on IRC then, I don't want to use dummy arguments as it's not a clean solution.

Comment: Do report what you find! I'm fairly curious.